# Unexpected behavior of minimal flow in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm creating a new flow and started from almost empty definition

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow routerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(routerInputChannel())
            .channel(routerOutputChannel())
            .get();
}
```

So far so good. But if I add simple wireTap line

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow routerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(routerInputChannel())
            .wireTap(m -> System.out.println(m))
            .channel(routerOutputChannel())
            .get();
}
```

I received exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'IntegrationFlow' can't consist of only one 'MessageChannel'. Add at lest '.bridge()' EIP-method before the end of flow.
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.get(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:2670)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowBuilder.get(IntegrationFlowBuilder.java:26)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.wireTap(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:329)
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.wireTap(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:263)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.config.RootConfiguration.routerFlow(RootConfiguration.java:29)
```

What is the reason of such exception?

I use Spring Integration **4.3.7.RELEASE** and Spring Integration Java DSL **1.1.4.RELEASE**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is indeed unexpected.

The `wireTap()` has signature:

```
public B wireTap(IntegrationFlow flow) {
```

Where `IntegrationFlow` is functional interface and therefore can be specified by the Lambda. At the same time the argument of that Lambda can really be sent to the `System.out.println()`. If we convert your Lambda to the interface implementation we'll see:

```
.wireTap(new IntegrationFlow() {

        @Override
        public void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> x) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }

})
```

As you see there is really no anything about the message you would expect with your Lambda for `.handle()`.

And you should see something like this in your logs:

```
org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowBuilder@6995bf68
```

That is exactly SOUT of the `System.out.println(IntegrationFlowDefinition)`...

So, to fix your problem we should have something like this:

```
.wireTap(flow -> flow.handle(System.out::println))
```

I don't know what we can do from the Framework perspective. I'm pretty sure any `@FunctionalInterface`-based construction suffers the same problem if we provide a Lambda with the `Object.toString()` signature. That is just some nasty side-effect of the syntax sugar IMO :-).

Comment: Ahhh... I see now. Thank you!